# package.json not found in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

My Dockerfile looks something like this.

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:8.11.3

RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY ./ /app

WORKDIR /app/build

RUN yarn global add serve
CMD ["serve", "-l", "3000"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

And then JenkinsFile looks something like this.

```
 node {
  try {

    stage('Checkout source code') {
        checkout scm
    }

    stage('Install packages') {
      sh("docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/app -w /app node yarn install")
      //sh("sudo chown -R jenkins: ./node_modules")
    }

    stage('Set the enviroment variables') {
      sh("echo set-env-variables")
      }

    stage('Build static assets') {

      sh("docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/app -w /app node yarn build")
    }
  }}
```

When i do run it on Jenkins,the console output says `error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/app"` and also it gives an error `sudo not found` even though i have added `jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` to /etc/sudoers file.

I run the commands listed in my Jenkinsfile on my terminal and they all work fine but when i run them on Jenkins , they dont work.

Comment: If you navigate to the `./app` folder is there a `package.json` file there?...

Comment: I am copying the entire current working dir to /app in docker container using `COPY ./ /app` in Dockerfile.So i suppose package.json should be present in the container.

Comment: If you are copying your entire files already under /app why mount pwd again?

Comment: I guess that i am not building the image using Dockerfile so its just making a temp container which gets destroyed after the execution. `docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/app -w /app node yarn build` , its just creating a temp container.